# tf.estimator.inputs.pandas_input_fn label tensor

Tags: pandas, tensorflow, input

Was trying out Tensorflow's built in `pandas_input_fn()` with a pandas dataframe that I named `training_examples`

It's a very simple dataframe, describing one set of features and labels; this is then passed as argument `x` in the `pandas_input_fn()` function as shown below, which, if I understand the docs correctly, should return an input function with the data already parsed into features and labels?

```
input_function = tf.estimator.inputs.pandas_input_fn(
x= training_examples,
y= None,
batch_size=128,
num_epochs=1,
shuffle=True,
queue_capacity=1000,
num_threads=1,
target_column='y'
)
```

However, when I then try and pass this function to the `.train()` method, I get an error as shown below:

```
ValueError: You must provide a labels Tensor. Given: None. Suggested 
troubleshooting steps: Check that your data contain your label feature. Check 
that your input_fn properly parses and returns labels.
```

Not sure what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: i'm not sure the y argument here is used to specify the name of the labels column? from [docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/estimator/inputs/pandas_input_fn)
`y`: pandas `Series` object. `None` if absent.

Comment: do you already have a column named `'y'`?

Comment: managed to work around it, by specifying `y= traning_examples['label column']`, but not sure this is the best way of doing it

Comment: don't know, never used tensor_flow, best thing to do is follow a tutorial and use their code and sample data to get a feel what you're supposed to do

Answer (score 1):

train_input_function zips up it's own tuple of features and labels. You're in the right track in your comments.

```
x = training_examples[[feature_column_list]]
y = training_examples[label_column_name]
```

Working with the full dataset (before splitting into train and test) I find it works effectively to produce train and test input functions like so. This makes use of sklearn's train_test_split function with 'stratify' to make sure the right ratio of cases have each category in the label.

```
sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

train_x, test_x, train_y, test_y = train_test_split(x, y, stratify=y)
```

At this point you can specify your input functions.

```
train_input_fn = tf.estimator.inputs.pandas_input_fn(x=train_x, y=train_y, shuffle=True, num_epochs=whatever, batch_size=whatever)

test_input_fn = tf.estimator.inputs.pandas_input_fn(x=test_x, y=test_y, shuffle=False, batch_size=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

try target_column=None and use the actual Y column in Y= training_examples['label/target']